# Modular content and syndication

Tags: 8

I am trying to sketch out a Drupal 8 based solution by which content is authored in a modular way, with an arbitrary number of different modular blocks of content,  that would also allow nodes to be pushed (or pulled) to other separate Drupal 8 installs. (The essential idea being that a set of editors have access to a set of simple modular blocks to build content which is likely to be duplicated across different separate sites and another set of editors have access to a more complicated set of blocks to build content that is not necessarily meant to be duplicated.)

So far I can't seem to find any obvious solutions, most seem to require knowledge of the content configuration beforehand. Is there an obvious solution I'm overlooking or just ignorant of?

A combination of [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) and [Deploy](https://www.drupal.org/project/deploy) module have been suggested to me. I'm still evaluating their combination to determine if it's suitable but any additional suggestions would be very helpful!

Comment: I would also check out Entity Construction Kit as an alternative to Paragraphs. One of the main advantages is that ECK entity content is reusable. That in combo with Inline Entity form makes it a powerful combo for modular structured content. As how Deploy handles that, I am not sure.

Comment: Paragraphs is great, but they are not designed to be reusable. However, I don't see why you couldn't use blocks for reusable content, and have a "block picker" paragraph type that is just an entity reference to a block. That would allow editors to select what blocks they like, in any sequence, and add unique content by other paragraph types if they have permission for those.

Comment: Content syndication is a great idea, but often is a pipe dream because what is really wanted is to copy the content and make modifications. That said, [Content Syndication Using Services and Feeds](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/content-syndication-using-services-and-feeds) by karens describes the approach that I initially came up with.

Comment: That seems so close to what I need! Some of the foundational modules are not ready for Drupal 8 yet, and that makes this not an option for me at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is currently not possible for Drupal 8, using community maintained modules. The Feeds Extensible Parsers module is not ready, which means the services+feeds method is not feasible, and the Deploy module is not ready. (Though methods may become available in the future for this particular workflow.)